# Представиться другим браузером. Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Написал свой браузер по уроку http://www.fandroid.info/urok-po-sozdaniyu-prostogo-brauzera-v-android-studio/. Подскажите я могу как-то изменить представление браузера? например чтобы сайты считали что я захожу через Firefox?

Comment: Написал свой браузер) Как звучит то))

Comment: [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: Пробую в loadurl вторым параметром передавать, не работает. Или туда можно только дополнительные заголовки вставлять?

Comment: Все разобрался WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0");